# How to find all positions of a character in a string without using enumerate or regex in Python?

Tags: python, string, loops

I tried using this:

```
def charFinder(st,ch):
    for i in range(len(st)):
        if st[i]==ch:
            print(st[i])

charFinder("abc abc abc", "a")
```

But this only prints the letter at position i, and using st.find(ch) prints only the first occurence. How would I find all occurences using a for loop so that it prints this:

```
0
4
8
```

Comment: Umm.. it's printing out the letter at position i because you're asking it to, when you do `print(st[i])`.  If you want the positions and not the letters, can you figure out what you should ask it to print instead?

Comment: Why don’t you want to use `enumerate` for this?

Comment: In my class, we haven't used enumerate yet so apparently there's a way to do it without using it and I need to find out since my midterm is tomorrow lol

Comment: Just `print(i)` instead of `print(st[i])`

Comment: Wow Ksai thank you how did I not realize that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
message = 'i love the way this works'
indexes = {}
for character, index in zip(message, range(len(message))):
       if character in indexes.keys():
              indexes[character] += [index]
       else:
              indexes.update({character: [index]})
print(indexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
def charFinder(st, ch):
    ch_pos_arr = []
    for i in range(len(st)):
        if st[i]==ch:
            ch_pos_arr.append(i)
    print(ch_pos_arr)
```

If you want more compact syntax you can use list comprehension:

```
def charFinder(st, ch)
    print([i for i in range(0, len(st)) if st[i] == ch])
```

Comment: looks like I've missed a couple of spaces, which is terrible with Python... Now all is corrected.)

Comment: Is it possible to do it using indexing? l'm not familliar with append, but thanks for the reply!

Comment: You can try to replace "ch_pos_arr.append(i)" with "ch_pos_arr += [i]".

Although I'm not sure whether it looks much simplier... XD